# Type and non-type template specialization

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, c++17

I would like to write a MP predictor for a type and a function. It seems that something is illegal:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class R>
struct X { 
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

// Specialization for type
template <>
struct X<int(int)> {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

// ERROR: Redefinition with diffrent kind
template <int (*F)(int)>
struct X { 
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};

int fun(int);

int main(int, char* []) 
{
    std::cout << "X<int>: " << X<int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "X<int(int)>: " << X<int(int)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "X<decltype(fun)>: " << X<decltype(fun)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "X<fun>: " << X<fun>::value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

More details:
What for?

1. To learn metaprogramming
2. To write a universal predictor that can say if call a function/an object instance with a given argument (something like is_callable from C++17)

Comment: You might find [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97298936e850a900) interesting. Or not.

Comment: Certainly something related and interesting even if does not solves the problem. So thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to achieve something like that?

What you're effectively asking is if you can overload class templates. No, you cannot.

However, you can certainly overload function templates - you can have one function template which takes one non-deduced template type parameter, specialize it, and then have another function template which takes one non-deduced template non-type parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class R> constexpr int X() { return 0; }    

// specialization for type
template <> constexpr int X<int(int)>() { return 1; }

// Redefinition with different kind
template <int (*F)(int)>
constexpr int X() { return 2; }

int fun(int);

int main(int, char* []) 
{
    std::cout << "X<int>: " << X<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "X<int(int)>: " << X<int(int)>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "X<decltype(fun)>: " << X<decltype(fun)>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "X<fun>: " << X<fun>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That prints 0, 1, 1, and 2, as desired.

Comment: And, with `constexpr` you can even use the output of the function as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. The template argument can only be a type or a value. In the declaration:

```
template <class R>
struct X {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};
```

you specify X to take a type as argument.

```
// ERROR: Redefinition with diffrent kind
template <int (*F)(int)>
struct X {
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};
```

You want to specialise X to take a value (a function pointer). That does collide with you first declaration of X. Therefore you get the redefinition error.

If you want to implement your predictor in a more general way, you will have to use the SFINAE pattern. I wrote something similar in my past, but abandoned it because it is too clumsy to use and error prone. I don't quite remember, but i think i found some corner cases, where it failed to work. For educational purposes I post the code here:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace Detail {

template <
    class Function,
    class Result,
    class Enable,
    class... Args
>
struct isFunctionImpl {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <
    class Function,
    class Result,
    class... Arg
>
struct isFunctionImpl <
    Function,
    Result,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<
            Result,
            decltype(std::declval<Function>()(*reinterpret_cast<Arg*>(0)...))
        >::value
    >::type,
    Arg...
> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

} // End of namespace Detail

template <
    class Function,
    class Result,
    class... Args
>
struct isFunction {
    static constexpr bool value = Detail::isFunctionImpl<Function, Result, void, Args...>::value;
};

int foo(int bar) {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Is function " << isFunction<decltype(foo), int, int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Is function " << isFunction<decltype(foo), int, std::string>::value << std::endl;
}
```